# How can I split any table/df dynamically depending on its number of elements and store each element as a list?

Tags: r, list, split

[image]I am trying to split a table on the basis of difference of the value of one column as follows:

> Creating a new table that contains information organised by chromosome numbers as lists

```
t2_s=split(tbl2, tbl2$chr)
```

this creates a list of lists. Each list contains up to 10,000 rows. I want to now extract each list and assign it a name dynamically, I want to be able to do this dynamically so that my program can handle any table with any size and any number of lists after splitting based on a column.

I tried the following but I think I am trying to apply Java logic to **R**:

```
counter = 1
for (j in t2_s){
   paste(c("chrList", counter), collapse = " ") <- (t2_s[[counter]])
   counter = counter + 1
}
```

I need something that would not choke **R** performance wise as well, as the size of each generated list will be huge as well.
I am an amateur coder so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea to move them out of the list, what can you do with those in the workspace that you can do with them stored into a list ?

Comment: I needed them as separate lists so that they would be less bulky to convert to JSON objects from R and then I was going to extract the JSON text files in java to use in plotly.js

If I try to convert the entire table to json with jsonlite, R crashes. I also need the information by chr# anyway later on (I also need to plot the entire table too though, in addition to be able to plot based on chr #), so I thought maybe I should break it down to avoid the R crash. Any suggestions would be welcome :)

Comment: it will not be "bulkier" if they stay in a list :), it's just a whole lot cleaner. with the accepted solution you're cluttering your workspace with hundredsof files it's really bad practice. Just use `t2_s=split(tbl2, tbl2$chr)` then `jsons <- lapply(t2_s, toJSON)` then another round of lapply to save them. If you tell me how you want your files to be named I can give you this step as well.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I wanted to name my extracted lists as chr_#, where # is the title of each list within t2_s and in the screenshot of the table added above, there are 13 lists titled 0-12. But sometimes they are numbered starting from 1 or something else so I wanted to keep the title of the sublists as it is when naming them: chr_title.

Comment: I'm suprised that R crashed for a table of less than 130k rows

Comment: try `Map(function(x,y) write(toJSON(x),paste0(your_folder,"/",y,".json")), t2_s, names(t2_s))`

Comment: You're awesome, thank you so much. This solved two of my issues - I now have text files that I can parse in java now and use in plotly.js - God bless you! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `assign()` for this task.

```
for (j in 1:length(t2_s)) {
    tmp <- paste("chrList", j, sep = "_")
    assign(tmp, t2_s[[j]])
}
```

This will create an object for each observation in your list. If you want to then create a list of all the objects you just created, you could do so with this.

```
# this will get a character vector of all objects in your global environment
all_env_objects <- ls()

# this will extract the newly created objects from the above code
all_new_objects <- all_env_objects[grep("chrList_", all_env_objects)]

# this will create a list containing all the objects your created
your_list <- do.call("list", mget(all_new_objects))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much - this is exactly what I needed :)